# Why chicken colour is like this?

Tags: chicken, chicken-breast

Following is chicken fillet picture and best before was 2 days ago. Why there discoloured?
Is it safe to consume?

[image]

Comment: I would very carefully consider some of your other food handling & storage methods too. Leaving a pack of half-unwrapped chicken in the fridge for days does not bode well for your other cross-contamination prevention habits. The fact that you don't even recognise what is wrong with it is extremely worrying.

Comment: Plus, chicken stays a lot fresher longer if you keep the remaining in a ziplock bag with air removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like it dried out. Presumably, you opened the package a few days ago, removed a few pieces, and kept the remainder in the fridge. It looks like you had another piece atop the two photographed ones, so the top stayed normal and the exposed sides went dry.

For further evidence, touch the darker parts and see if they feel drier than the light pink ones.

Comment: What to do wiith it, the that part? cut if off, how to know if it is ok to consume?

Comment: @localhost If it is only dried out, that's completely irrelevant for food safety. Just make your decision on throwing out or not as if the dryness weren't there. If you decide to eat it, the dry part will have a noticeably different texture after eating. You can throw it out for taste reasons, or keep it for budget or sustainability reasons, as you prefer.

Comment: *"another piece atop the two"*-  I'd be more inclined to think the top cover plastic sheet was just dropped roughly back in place, which has kept the very tops moist where it touched.

Comment: Can you add your comment to the actual answer? It contains additional useful information to the question OP asked.

Answer (score 2):

"When in doubt, throw it out."

Guaranteed food safety is worth the ten bucks or so for new chicken.